# Find all the possible $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $1125 = x^2 + y^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, gaussian-integers

I want to find all the possible $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $1125 = x^2 + y^2$ using the following result:

The representations of $n$ as a sum of two squares are determined by the possible choices of the $p_i$ in the Gaussian prime decomposition (i.e. choosing signs $a_j \pm b_j i$).

$1125 = 3^2 (2+i)^2 (2-i)^2$ is the Gaussian prime decomposition of $1125$ and I can spot solutions as $(30,15)$ but how can I find all of them? How many are there?

Comment: The title and body of the question don't match. The title seems to suggest that you're interested in the number of solutions, whereas in the body you ask about the actual solutions.

Comment: The On-Line Encyclopedia Of Integer Sequences has [some information](https://oeis.org/A000161).

Comment: $1125 = 3^2 5^\color{red}{3}$ and $5 = |2+i|^2$ implies $1125 = a^2 + b^2$ where
$$a + bi = 3i^{u} (2+i)^v(2-i)^{\color{red}{3}-v}\quad\text{ for }\quad 0 \le u < 4,
0 \le v \le \color{red}{3}$$
The number of possible $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ is $4\cdot (\color{red}{3}+1) = 16$.

Comment: Of course, that's counting, say, $(30,15)$ as different from $(30,-15)$, etc.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536097/representing-a-given-number-as-the-sum-of-two-squares?rq=1), which gives it for  $1885$, but works similarly here.

Comment: @achillehui what is the formula in general? I see for example that for $45 = 3^2 5$ there are 8 different ways.

Comment: @join, let $2^e \times \prod\limits_{j=1}^{n_p} p_j^{f_j} \times \prod\limits_{k=1}^{n_q} q_k^{g_k}$ be prime factorization of $n$ ( $p_j \equiv 1 \pmod 4$,  $q_k\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ ).
If any $g_k$ is odd,  $n$ cannot be a sum of squares. Otherwise, express each $p_j$ as $a_j^2 + b_j^2$. Solutions for $n = a^2+b^2$ will have the form:
$$a + bi = i^d (1+i)^e \times \prod_{j=1}^{n_p} (a_j + b_j i )^{s_j} (a_j - b_j i)^{f_j - s_j}\times \prod_{k=1}^{n_q} q_k^{g_k/2}$$
where $0 \le d < 4$ and $0 \le s_j \le f_j$ for $1 \le j \le n_p$. The  number of solutions is $4\prod_{j=1}^{n_p} (f_j + 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a very detailed explanation of the solution in "Abstract Algebra" by Dummit and Foote, pag. 291.

**Theorem.**

If $n=2^kp_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r}q_1^{b_1}\cdots q_s^{b_s}$ where $p_i \equiv 1 \bmod(4)$ and $q_i \equiv 3 \bmod(4)$, then:

1) $n$ can be written as sum of squares, i.e. $n=A^2 + B^2$ with $A$ and $B$ integers, if and only if every $b_i$ is even.

2) If (1) holds the number of different ways to write $n$ as a sum of two squares are $4(a_1+1)\cdots(a_r+1)$.

*Example.*

$1125=3^25^3$, the precedent theorem tell us that there are $16$ ways to write it as a sum of squares. We'll show throught an example how to find them.

Every prime congruent $1$ modulo $4$ can be factorized in two conjugate irreducible gaussian integers, for example $5=(2+i)(2-i)$. Instead every prime congruent $3$ modulo $4$ is irreducible also in the guassian integers ring.

The integers we're looking for are the solutions of $A + iB = (2+i)^{e_1}(2-i)^{e_2}3$ with $e_1$ and $e_2$ not negative integers such that $e_1+e_2=3$. Infact:

$A^2 + B^2 = \\
=N(A+iB)= \\
=(A+iB)(\overline{A+iB})= \\
=((2+i)^{e_1}(2-i)^{e_2}3)\overline{((2+i)^{e_1}(2-i)^{e_2}3)}=\\
=((2+i)^{e_1}(2-i)^{e_2}3)((2-i)^{e_1}(2+i)^{e_2}3)= \\
=(2+i)^3(2-i)^33^2=\\
=5^33^2=\\
=1125\\$

Varing $e_1$ we can find all the solutions:

For $e_1=0$:

$A+iB=\\
=(2-i)^33=\\
=6-33i$

Inverting the signs and the order we get 8 solutions $1125= (\pm6)^2 +(\pm 33)^2 = (\pm 33)^2 +(\pm 6)^2$

For $e_1=1$:

$A+iB=\\
=(2+i)(2-i)^23=\\
=30-15i$

For others 8 solutions $1125= (\pm30)^2 +(\pm 15)^2 = (\pm 15)^2 +(\pm 30)^2$

For $e_1=2$ or $e_1=3$ we obtain the same results infact we've already reached the 16 solutions predicted.

Comment: "specular"? should that be "similar"?

Comment: I've edited the sentence. I meant that for each $(e_1, e_2)$ the complements $(3-e_1, 3-e_2)$ give us the same $A$ and $B$ but with differents signs, solutions we've already into account.